# Looping through a github image directory using html

Tags: php, html, ajax, github-pages

I'm trying to add a gallery to my github pages.
In my username.github.io directory, I have an assets/images folder containing some images. I need to loop through all the images and show them.

I've been looking for a solution for a long time and saw some mentioning AJAX and PHP, none of which I know at all.

I tried writing this code but it doesn't work :(

```
{%for picture in page.image%}
    <div class="image-wrapper">
          <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ page.image }}/{{picture}}">
               <p>text</p>
                  <!-- <img src="{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/images/picture"> -->
          </a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm guessing
`for pictures in page.image` doesn't work like I thought it would in python. Is there a way around this?

using
`<a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ page.image }}">` insted of `<a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ page.image }}/{{picture}}">`  does show the link to my images directory tho.

Hope my noob question hasen't bothered anyone    (ﾟωﾟ；)

Comment: HTML is markup language and doesn't have any loops. This one looks like some template engine (probably Smarty?) which is something like PHP with user friendly syntax.

Comment: @jax-p I,m guessing you're talking about the jekyll themes that github pages use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `page.image` is not an array you can loop on, so I would rather go to check it, you should have a full array of your images and then go loop them in your template. 
 Please, provide all the input and output data you have so we can help you fast and with ease ( maybe codebox ? ).

Comment: here's my code on github https://github.com/TahsinTariq/tahsintariq.github.io/blob/master/_layouts/gallery_layout.html

Comment: @TahsinTariq Could you show `page` variable here ( I mean, it's content )? Because if you tried to use it like this - `<a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ page.image }}">` and it does work without any exception - this means that your `page.image` is not an array itself, and you cannot loop for it.

Comment: Here notice the `layout : gallery_layout` and `image : assets/images` these the first calls the layout and the second is refering to the page.image 
https://github.com/TahsinTariq/tahsintariq.github.io/blob/master/writings/Gallery.md

Comment: I think you are simply looking for something like this:
`https://jekyllrb.com/docs/static-files/`